How to analyze time varying covariate random effect
I am running a multilevel growth curve model to examine predictors of social anhedonia (SA) trajectory through ages 12, 15 and 18. SA is a continuous numeric variable. The age variable (Index1) has been coded as 0 for age 12, 1 for age 15 and 2 for age 18. I am currently using a time varying predictor, stress (LSI), which was measured at ages 12, 15 and 18, to examine whether trajectory/variation in LSI predicts difference in SA trajectory. LSI is a continuous numeric variable. The data has been converted to long format with SA in 1 column, LSI in the other, ID in another and age in another column.
the LSI time varying predictor was grand mean centered. Should I use a person-mean centered LSI as the random effect instead, as I read the following paper (https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/2167696815592726?journalCode=eaxa) and they have mentioned to use a person-mean centered value, but I am unsure how to create the model with a person-mean centered value. Would the model look like:
RandomLSI <- lmer(SA ~ Index1* LSI+ (1+Index1+LSIPMC|ID),data = LSIDATA, control = lmerControl(optimizer ="bobyqa"), REML=TRUE) summary(RandomLSI)
Note: LSI is the grand mean centered values, LSIPMC is the person mean centered values.

To create a person-mean centered variable, you need to first create a person mean for each individual and then subtract each person's mean from their score at a given occasion. You can use functions within various packages for this, including the center() function in the mlmtools package or use dplyr().
library(mlmtools)    
center(dataset = LSIDATA, x = "Index1", grouping = "ID")

library(dplyr)
LSIDATA <- LSIDATA |> group_by(ID) |> mutate(pmn_Index1 = mean(Index1)) |> ungroup() |> 
                   mutate(cwp_Index1 = Index1-pmn_Index1)

Then you simply switch out Index1 in your model statement with the new centered variable.
One thing you need to be aware of is that time-varying covariates can be problematic if they themselves have a systematic time trend. In that case, you may need to switch your model such that you model both SA and Index1 in a multivariate linear mixed model. You can do this in brms quite easily if you are willing to go Bayesian or you can do it using lme(). See https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/ILD_Ch05_2017_MultivariateMLM.html
